# After playing a Wild card, must a player discard again?

Tags: uno

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28card_game%29),

> Wild - Player declares next color to be matched (may be used on any turn).

After this player discards a Wild card and announces the next color, must he discard another card, or does the player next to him proceed to discard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He will not discard second card this round. The wild card was his play. Play proceeds to the next player with the new colour selected.